# ASP MVC 4 EntityValidationErrors

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have an object "product" build from a database. it has 3 attributes :
- Id can't be NULL
- Ref can't be NULL
- Designation can be NULL

So I'm using an AjaxForm and @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Designation) to update the "Designation" field
My problem is when my Controller received the "product" object, Product's Id is well filled with the original value, however Product's Ref is null

I thought about 2 solutions :
Add a Ref Field in my AjaxForm not editable, or the worst : In my controller research the ref of my product using the Id ( very bad :s )

Could you advice me about how to do this clean.
Thank you !

Comment: Add a hidden field for the Ref property.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably have to add in the Ref Field, so that the page knows about mapping that field when it goes back to your controller, but you can make it hidden using [HiddenFor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.inputextensions.hiddenfor%28v=vs.108%29.aspx):

`@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Ref)`